# Beautiful Soup .get_text() does not equal Python string when it should

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to grab text from an html element.

I am then using a loop and if statement to compare that text to a list of words. If they match I want to return a confirmation.

However, the code is not confirming any matches, even though print statements show there are in fact matches.

```
def findText():
    text = ""

    url = 'www.site.com'


    #Get url and store
    page = requests.get(url)
    #Get page content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

    els = soup.select(".className")

    lists = els[1].select(".className2")
            for l in lists:
                try:
                    text=l.find("li").get_text()
                except(AttributeError):
                    text="null"
    return text

def isMatch(text):
    #Open csv file
    listFile = open('list.csv', 'rb')
    #prep file to be read
    newListFile =csv.reader(listFile)


    match = ""
    for r in newListFile:
        if r[0]==text.lower():
            match = True
        else:
            match = False

    return match

    congressCSVFile.close()
```

> > match is always False in the output

print(r[0]) returns (let's just say) "cat" in terminal

print(text) also returns "cat" in terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is the problem, or at least one of them. Once you find a record that matches, you *keep going*. `match` will only end up `True` if the *last record* matches. To fix this, simply `return` when you find a match:

```
for r in newListFile:
    if r[0]==text.lower():
        return True
return False
```

The `match` variable is not needed.

Better yet, use the `any()` function:

```
return any(r[0] == text.lower() for r in newListFile)
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed that. However, the code is still not working/producing a match. Also Before writing this post I've tried printing a confirmation whenever there is a match in the loop but nothing ever printed. But thanks for pointing out this issue.

Comment: Actually, it turned out that there were two issues. This was one and just solved the other. Needed to lower() r[0] as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your try: `text = l.find("li").get_text(strip=True)`

Soup and html in general adds a significant amount of white space.  If you don't parse it out with the strip parameter then you may never get a match unless the white space is included in your list file.

Comment: Thanks, this did not solve the issue. Also when I print the values, I don't see additional white space in either, they appear to be exact matches.

Comment: Np, glad you got the answer and hope my answer helps somewhat in other projects to come.